# Hasura User Role Inherited Permissions from Anonymous

Tags: graphql, roles, hasura

I'm trying to grant access so that users can access all user information about themselves + non-sensitive information about others in the user table.

I thought user would inherit permissions from anonymous user which would give them access to the non-sensitive data of all users. This doesn't seem to be the case.

Is there a simple way to do this?

[image: screenshot of user permissions]

[image: Screenshot of anonymous permissions]

Answer (score 1):

Figured out to create an SQL view for the private user info and set permissions for those columns. Set the remaining columns as public.